Is the ratio of probabilities of two points in a continuous distribution equal to the ratio of their PDFs?
Let $ X $ be a continous random variable.
I understand that $ P(X=a) = 0 $, for any point $ a $ in the sample space.
My question refers to the ratio $ \frac{P(X = a)}{P(X = b)} $. My intuition tells me that:
$$ \frac{P(X = a)}{P(X = b)} = \frac{f_x(a)}{f_x(b)}$$
where $ f_x $ is the probability density function for $ X $.
How can I prove this?

You always have, informally, that $\mathbb P(X\in [x,x+dx]) = f_X(x)dx$. If you use this rule of thumb, take the quotient and let $dx\to 0$, you would get what you want.

By L'Hopital's Rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{P(a \le X \le a+h)}{P(b \le X \le b + h)} &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f_x(a+h)}{f_x(b+h)}\\&=\frac{f_x(a)}{f_x(b)}
\end{align*}$$
But the initial $\frac{P(X=a)}{P(X=b)}$ is not well defined, since it is $0/0$. But your intuition is correct, just about the limit as the widths of the desired intervals approaches 0.
